# Не получается подключить плагин поворота картинки на 360 градусов

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужен именно [этот плагин](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/s7/viewers_ref/c_html5_spin_viewer_about.html) тут есть [демо](https://s7d9.scene7.com/s7viewers/html5/SpinViewer.html?asset=Scene7SharedAssets/SpinSet_Sample&stagesize=500,400) пример, пробовал подключить его, но не получается вывести свои картинки

```js
var spinViewer = new s7viewers.SpinViewer({
    "containerId":"s7viewer",
    "params":{
        "asset":"Scene7SharedAssets/SpinSet_Sample",
        "serverurl":"http://s7d1.scene7.com/is/image/"
    }
}).init();
```

```css
.holder {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20%;
    top: 20%;
    width: 60%;
height: 60%;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7d1.scene7.com/s7viewers/html5/js/SpinViewer.js"></script>
<div class="holder">

<div id="s7viewer" style="position:relative"></div>
</div>
```

как я понял то данная строчка `"serverurl":"http://s7d1.scene7.com/is/image/"` отвечачет за подгрузку картинок, но почему-то не выходит создав каталоги is и image вывести свои картинки, вадает много разных ошибок. Как сделать так чтобы выводило нужные мне картинки

Comment: Выводит много разных ошибок, а мы все тут эсперы, которые могут читать мысли.

Comment: http://verstka.ru.mitgroup.ru/3d/ вот пример. "serverUrl":"is/image", путь к картинкам такой

Comment: У вас написано, путь не найдет. Пробуйте сначала переводить ошибки.

Comment: И что, путь не найден к json файлу, в примере я не нашел где он генерится, я его вставил в ручную, и не помогло

Comment: http://prntscr.com/e55cni

Comment: там поворот картинок работает как я понял через json который как я понял настраивает canvas чтоб поворачивать картинки

Comment: У вас все картинки находятся рядом с файлом, а вы указываете какой-то левый путь и удивляетесь, почему не работает

Comment: Этот плагин все равно работает только в связки с java бэкендом, найдите другой.

Answer (score 0):

Плагин работает только с javascript бэкендом судя по документации.
Используйте например такой jquery плагин [ThreeSixty](http://nick-jonas.github.io/threesixtyjs/). Там все просто.
Достаточно указать количество сторон и создать такое же количество картинок.

Comment: да плагинов то много чтоб крутить картинки, проблема то в том что заказчик уперся, хочу этот и все(( а вот по поводу java бэкэнда чет не увидел даже где это написано, можете показать где, спс.

Comment: Чем дольше я читаю документацию, тем меньше я понимаю, как поднять сервак который они хотят для рендеринга изображений.

Comment: ну то есть для работы нужен json как я понял, только где описано как и что подключать?(((

Comment: Да я вот и сам не могу разабрать как там все подрубается, вот катерпиллера сайт http://www.cat.com/ru_RU/products/new/equipment/underground-longwall/armored-face-conveyors/18318734.html там есть вкладка КРУГОВОЙ ОБЗОР http://prntscr.com/e55lgx и тоже не понятно как все подключается(((

Comment: там используется flash player который через пару месяцев нигде вообще не будет работать.

Comment: Не не не, там есть вкладка именно с данным плагином, посмотрите скриншет

Comment: Адобе использует свою систему, а вы уже к ней подключаетесь.
[Adobe Experience Manager](https://landing.adobe.com/en/na/geometrixx/rich-media-assets-demo.html)

Comment: Отписал в сапорт, а мне ответили, что это не их плагин, и что писать надо разработчикам, но кто они(((